# Kafka multiple consumers with many deserializers in one group (same groupId) cannot pick the right listener

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have multiple consumers in the same topic for different event types, with deserializer components for each event. When a message is received the deserializer is not the correct one and the event is not consumed. After a couple of retries it takes the correct listener but in this case we miss a lot of messages.
But when the listeners are in different groups everything works as expected.

Any ideas how kafka chose which deserializer to pick and then consume the messages.

Config:

```
kafka:
    "FirstEventType":
      "[bootstrap.servers]": ${KAFKA_CONSUMER_BROKER_LIST:localhost:9092}
      "[group.id]": GroupOne
      "[client.id]": firstEventType
      "[auto.offset.reset]": earliest
      "[key.deserializer]": org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      "[value.deserializer]":org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      "[spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class]": com.my.pack.svc.kafka.deserializers.FirstEventTypeDeserializer
      "[messageType]": FirstEventType
      topic: topicOne
    "SecondEventType":
      "[bootstrap.servers]": ${KAFKA_CONSUMER_BROKER_LIST:localhost:9092}
      "[group.id]": GroupOne
      "[client.id]": secondEventType
      "[auto.offset.reset]": earliest
      "[key.deserializer]": org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      "[value.deserializer]": org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      "[spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class]": com.ft.subs.b2cfulfilsvc.kafka.deserializers.SecondEventTypeDeserializer
      "[messageType]": SecondEventType
      topic: topicOne
```

Kafka listeners:

```
@KafkaListener(
      topics = "topicOne",
      containerFactory = "FirstEventTypeFactory",
      groupId = "GroupOne)
  public void onFirstEventType(
      FirstEventType eventType) {
   ....
  }
```

```
@KafkaListener(
      topics = "topicOne",
      containerFactory = "SecondEventTypeFactory",
      groupId = "GroupOne)
  public void onSecondEventType(
      SecondEventType eventType) {
   ....
  }
```

```
@Component
public class FirstEventTypeDeserializer
    extends AbstractMessageDeserializer<FirstEventType> {}
```

```
@Component
public class SecondEventTypeDeserializer
    extends AbstractMessageDeserializer<SecondEventType> {}
```

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
...

public abstract class AbstractMessageDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<T> {}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. use a different topic for each type.

Comment: FWIW - you should follow Spring Boot autoconfiguration structure, not define your own https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties ; this way it'll be clearer what is actually possible from the API and is easier to follow for others familiar with the API

Answer (score 0):

The result of your execution is correct. Several consumers in the same group cause only one of them to consume from one partition in that topic.

You probably need to look into a `@KafkaHandler` instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#class-level-kafkalistener.